# Flex TextArea, increase number of rows to more than 100

Tags: flex3, textarea

I am using TextArea to display some text information in rows in flex gui, it automatically restricts the number of lines to display to 100 lines. But I want more than 100 lines in the text area.

How can I increase number of lines to display?

Answer (score 1):

never heard about that limitation. Here there's an article that deals with textArea numLines:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/05/08/determining-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textarea-control-in-flex/